# EC2 Port 9292 filtered after adding it in security groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, faye, amazon-ec2

I've added the port to the inbound policy of the security group running in my EC2 instance:

> Custom TCP Rule
>   TCP
>   9292
>   0.0.0.0/0

But when I nmpap it I get that it is filtered. I can't find any way to change it or understand why is filtered in the console. Does anyone knows how to achieve a full port management on AWS or what could be going on in this case?

I've checked that ufw (ubuntu firewall)

Thanks!

Comment: You may also check the subnet settings

Answer (score 0):

There was another process which was using the 9292 in localhost. So it was filetring all outside connections.In this case I was starting faye server with the standar command which starts faye server under localhost.

I fixed it starting faye under the dns name of the server and it works.